# Radial gradient using pstricks

Tags: pstricks, gradient

I created the following image with `pstricks`:

[image]

The fading fillings are generated by:

```
\psline[linewidth=10cm,linecolor=Black,linestyle=fade,fadepoints=500,fadeto=transparency](5,6)(5,1)
\psline[linewidth=10cm,linecolor=LightSkyBlue,linestyle=fade,fadepoints=500,fadeto=transparency](5,1)(5,6)
```

Since, the Earth itself is round, I obviously cannot use this drawing if precision is needed. Therefore, I created the next one:

[image]

My question is: **How can I implement the same fading atmosphere effect in this situation?** I'm sorry but at this late stage I cannot switch to TikZ anymore.

Code:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[11pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{border=1cm}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-func,pst-math,pst-grad}

\begin{document}
\psset{arrowsize=6pt,linewidth=1pt} 
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=none](-3,0.25)(13,10)
    \psarc[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=LightSkyBlue,linestyle=none]{-}(5,0){8}{0}{180}
    \psarc[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=ForestGreen!50,linestyle=solid]{-}(5,0){5}{0}{180}

    \psline{<->}(5,0)(5,5)
    \rput[l](5.1,2.5){$R_\oplus$}

    \psline{<->}(5,5)(5,8)
    \rput[l](5.1,6.5){$h$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I did some tries using

```
\multido{\ny=7.0+0.01,\ni=0.00+0.002}{750}{\psarc[linewidth=0.15mm,linestyle=solid,linecolor=Black,strokeopacity=\ni]{-}(5,0){\ny}{0}{180}}
\multido{\ny=5.0+0.01,\ni=1.00+-0.0025}{400}{\psarc[linewidth=0.15mm,linestyle=solid,linecolor=LightSkyBlue,strokeopacity=\ni]{-}(5,0){\ny}{0}{180}}
```

but this is really slow and gives a comparable large pdf file.
[image]

Comment: It's best practice to include seperate `.pdf` files in your main document, with precompiled images and the likes. If the file size of the pdf file bothers you, there are alternative formats, I think PDF-A is one of them (don't know about compatibility with `pstricks` in this context).

Answer (score 3):

there are several possibilies to play with the fillstyle `ccslope`. See documentation for more examples:

```
\documentclass[11pt,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-slpe}

\begin{document}
\psset{arrowsize=6pt,linewidth=1pt,unit=0.5} 
\begin{pspicture*}(-11,0)(11,11)
\psframe*(-11,0)(11,11)
\pscircle[linestyle=none,fillstyle=ccslope,slopebegin=blue,slopeend=black](0,0){11}
\pscircle[linestyle=none,fillstyle=ccslope,slopebegin=white,slopeend=blue](0,0){10}
  \psarc[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=ForestGreen!50,linestyle=solid]{-}(0,0){6}{0}{180}
  \psline{<->}(0,6)      \uput[0](0,2.5){$R_\oplus$}
  \psline{<->}(0,6)(0,10)\uput[0](00,8){$h$}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]